# Compas Calibration

Tags: android, compass-geolocation

i want to show toast to calibrate the compass if it is not well calibrated before using compass
as in Iphone  Compass Calibration toast appears if compass is not well calibrated. how to achieve this to aware the User to calibrate the compass before using it .For further clarification Screen shot is attached.  [image] 
thank you

Comment: So the problem is toasting the message or calibrating the device?

Comment: the problem is to show toast when compass is not calibrated

Comment: So if you able to determine that you device is not calibrated, Then one line of code .. Toast.makeText(app.getBaseContext(),"Enclose String here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();